# PHP email form is not sending all fields

Tags: php, html, email, forms, field

here is my html form

```
<form  action="formmail1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<li>
Name<br /><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="50" maxlength="50" /> <br />
First and Last Name<br /><br />
</li>

<li>
Phone<br /><input name="phone" Type="text" id="email" size="12" maxlength="12"/><br />
___-___-____<br /><br />
</li>

<li>
Email<br />
<input name="email" Type="text" id="email" size="50"/><br />
Valid email address<br /><br />
</li>

<li>
How do you want to be contacted?<br />
<input Type="radio" name="how_to_be_contacted" id="r1" class="radio" value="1" /><label for="r1">Email</label><br />
<input Type="radio" name="how_to_be_contacted" id="r2" class="radio" value="2" /><label for="r1">Phone</label><br /><br />
</li>

<li>
I would like information about...<br />
<input name="aquatic_therapy" type="checkbox" id="aquatic_therapy" />Aquatic Therapy&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="occupational_therapy" type="checkbox" id="occupational_therapy" />Occupational Therapy<br />
<input name="speech_therapy" type="checkbox" id="speech_therapy" />Speech Therapy&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="reflex_integration" type="checkbox" id="reflex_integration" />Reflex Integration
<br />
Select all that apply<br />
</li>
<br />
<li>
Message<br />
<textarea name="message" cols="50" rows="10" id="message"></textarea><br />
</li>

</ol>

<input id="submit" type="submit">
```

Here is my PHP

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
//if "email" is filled out, send email

  //send email
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
    $phone = $_REQUEST['phone'] ;
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
    $how_do_you_want_to_be_contcted = $_REQUEST['how_do_you_want_to_be_contcted'] ;
    $information = $_REQUEST['information'] ;
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
    mail("email@nowhere.com", "Subject: Contact Us Form",
    $message "From: $email" );
    echo "Thank you for using our mail form";


else
  //if "email" is not filled out, display the form
  echo "<form method='post' action='mailform.php'>
  Email: <input name='email' type='text' /><br />
  Subject: <input name='subject' type='text' /><br />
  Message:<br />
  <textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
  </textarea><br />
  <input type='submit' />
  </form>";
```

All that is sending is message text field but none of the other fields....

Comment: Can you paste the results of "print_r($_REQUEST);" on your form processor script?  Just add it to the top of the script and exit();

Answer (score 2):

`$_REQUEST['how_do_you_want_to_be_contcted']` won't work because the field name in the HTML code is `how_to_be_contacted`.

You're defining the phone field as `$phone` and then referring to `$emailphone`. That clearly won't work either.

```
mail("eweb@gmail.com", "Subject: Contact Us Form", $emailphone
$message "From: $email" );
```

This has syntax errors, so can't work at all as shown.

You haven't escaped any of the input values, so if someone enters something with invalid data it could break the program and/or result in the site getting hacked.

Answer (score 1):

Checkboxes and Radio buttons aren't sent unless checked.

Comment: in my test I am checking the boxes but they are not sending - there is something missing in my php

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possibility:

the request name you are asking for is: how_do_you_want_to_be_contcted
in your form you call it: how_to_be_contacted